# Android - Samsung issue - ListView fast scrolling with double drag

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, scroll, jazzylistview

Today I noticed that when you do a quick double drag in a ListView, the list will go to the end or the beginning of the list. It appears that this only happens in Samsung phones.

This has become an issue because I am adding JazzyListView animation effects to the elements on the list and they crash whenever this quick movement happens. (NullPointerException whenever the ListView.layoutChildren method is invoked)

Maybe I will need to modify the library, or is it any way to disable this ListView behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this effect is called "**DOUBLE FLING**", it appears in logcat whenever I do it, unfortunately in AbsListView the only thing you can do about flinging is setting friction and velocity scale. If someone knows how to disable the effect it would be great (*However that may not be the best solution for this problem, as the users may be familiar with that behavior*)

What I did (my quick + dirty solution) was to modify the JazzyListView library, specifically JazzyHelper class, only validating that the item is not null before applying animation:

```
           while (firstVisibleItem + indexAfterFirst < mFirstVisibleItem) {
                View item = view.getChildAt(indexAfterFirst);
                if(item != null) {
                    doJazziness(item, firstVisibleItem + indexAfterFirst, -1);
                }

                indexAfterFirst++;
            }

            int indexBeforeLast = 0;
            while (lastVisibleItem - indexBeforeLast > mLastVisibleItem) {
                View item = view.getChildAt(lastVisibleItem - firstVisibleItem - indexBeforeLast);

                if(item != null) {
                    doJazziness(item, lastVisibleItem - indexBeforeLast, 1);
                }

                indexBeforeLast++;

            }
```

I believe that I should modify something about instance property mFirstVisibleItem, else the fastscrolling removes the animation on displaying items. However, my solution works for anyone who wants to quickly solve this issue.